# Hive derby metastore always gets corrupted

Tags: sql-server, hadoop, hive, derby, sqoop

I am new to Big data and Hadoop. I am using Sqoop to transfer data from SQL Server to HDFS and Hive. While I am using derby for Hive metatsore, I get the following error initially

```
FAILED: HiveException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
```

As suggested on other stackoverflows, I have run the following command and it fixes the issue for the first time and I am able to see tables in Hive

```
sudo $HIVE_HOME/bin/schematool -dbType derby -initSchema
```

But after some time, for example a day, when I reopen the Hive, it again gives me the same error as stated above and to resolve this I have to again re initialize the derby db which actually deletes every thing in Hive, i.e. tables.

Is there any way that I can fix the metastore without deleting anything or I am doing something wrong.

Thank You

Comment: Can you gather more information about what *exactly* is going wrong? The HiveException message should contain considerably more detail about what is wrong. Try looking for more complete information in underlying log files if the tool you are using is only printing that summary message to the screen.

Comment: I am only getting this message FAILED: HiveException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
First day I do initialize it, add some tables, next day it gives me the same error again, if you can help me to get the specific log file, I can attach them here.